# Delphi AsyncCalls Deadlock when Terminating the Threads (com+ dll finalization)

Tags: multithreading, delphi

I have a big Delphi 2007 project, and I use [AsyncCall](http://andy.jgknet.de/blog/bugfix-units/asynccalls-29-asynchronous-function-calls/)

I have extracted and tested the multithreading code in a single console application and everything works fine.

My Delphi 2007 project produces a COM DLL and I have some unit tests that are written in C# - mstest that calls the DLL.

The unit tests hang quite often randomly (tests passed) and i found out it happens at the AsyncCall unit - finalizatoin section that frees the ThreadPool.

```
destructor TThreadPool.Destroy;
var
  I: Integer;
  Call: TInternalAsyncCall;
begin
  FMaxThreads := FThreadCount; // Do not allocation new threads
  FDestroying := True; // => Sync in this thread because there is no other thread (required for FAsnycCallHead.Free)

  // Allow the threads to terminate if there is no task
  for I := FThreadCount - 1 downto 0 do
    FThreads[I].Terminate;
  // Wake up all sleeping threads and keep them awake so they can terminate
  SetEvent(FThreadTerminateEvent);
  // Wait and destroy the threads
****Hangs here -------->      for I := FThreadCount - 1 downto 0 do   
****------->        FThreads[I].Free;

  ReleaseAutoDeleteAsyncCalls;

  // Clean up not yet released AutoDelete InternalAsyncCalls.
  while FAsyncCallHead <> nil do
  begin
    Call := FAsyncCallHead.FNext;
    CheckAutoDelete(FAsyncCallHead);
    FAsyncCallHead := Call;
  end;

  CloseHandle(FThreadTerminateEvent);
  CloseHandle(FWakeUpEvent);
  CloseHandle(FMainThreadSyncEvent);
  DeallocateHWnd(FMainThreadVclHandle);
  DeleteCriticalSection(FAsyncCallsCritSect);

  inherited Destroy;
end;
```

If I remove

```
  for I := FThreadCount - 1 downto 0 do
    FThreads[I].Free;
```

It then works fine. I can't reproduce this in a simple example and can't think of any reasons that could hang the threads when terminating.

I believe it is very similar to the issues raised here:

http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=29843

> If a thread stops, it calls ThreadExit from Classes:ThreadProc And
>   ThreadExit calls the DLLEntryProc with DLL_THREAD_DETACH. Only one
>   thread in a process can be in a DLL initialization or detach routine
>   at a time.
>
> The problem is that the finalization of a com+ dll is run from the
>   DLL_THREAD_DETACH, so that the Classes:TThread.WaitFor will wait
>   indefinitly because the thread won't terminate because it can't handle
>   its DLL_THREAD_DETACH till the finalization finishes.

**update**

I have spent several days finding out the causes, and there is a work around which is to execute the finalization section of AsyncCall unit manually.

It is nothing to do with the algorithms, because even very simple code can cause problem in com+ dll.

Here are the steps to reproduce:

create a com+ dll
create a method that has the following code:
make sure TestAsync is called and you will notice the deadlock when the thread pool (from AsyncCall) is cleaning up the threads.

```
procedure Test(int i: integer); cdecl;
begin
  Exit;
end;

procedure TestAsyn;
var
  t: IAsyncCall;
begin
  t := AsyncCall(@Test, [0])
  t.Sync;
end;
```

Comment: You need to find a way to reproduce it in a simple example, or spend some time debugging your own code to figure out the problem. We can't debug code for you we can't access, and in order to provide code we can use you need to provide a MCVE. The process of figuring out how to provide one usually solves the problem.

Comment: You also need to spend more time attempting to solve problems yourself before posting here. You're averaging at least 3 questions per day every day for at least the last week, which shows very little effort working on figuring things out (including how to create an MCVE) before just posting a question. We should be the place of *last resort*, after you've exhausted every other means of trying to solve the problem. As many of the questions you've posted recently are duplicates, it's a clear indication you're doing little or no research yourself first.

Comment: Do you have any `TThread.Synchronize` calls in your threads/tasks? This is one main reason for dead locks in the case of freeing a thread

Comment: no... I just use simple AsynCall() and Sync method

Comment: I believe it is very similar to the issues raised here:  http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=29843

Comment: re-edited the question and I hope somebody can help me out here.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to do something that you're not allowed to do within initialization/finalization of a dll.

You'll need to run that finalization code from somewhere else. Usually this is done inside of a helper function that the dll exports. The other option is to run the finalization when the last com object of your dll is freed.

The exported function [`DllCanUnloadNow`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa753617(v=vs.85).aspx#tip2) looks like a candidate for terminating the threads.